# Will a modern C++ compiler optimize away false constexpr conditionals?

Tags: c++, debugging, compiler-optimization, constexpr

All throughout my code I have debugging conditionals in the form of:

```
if (Globals::DEBUG_MODE) std::cout << "debugging info" << std::endl;
```

`DEBUG_MODE` is a `constexpr bool` in a global constants header file.

My question is, when I get ready to release my software and I do some final optimizations, can I just turn that DEBUG_MODE bool off and the compiler will remove all those conditionals since they evaluate to false during compile time? Or, if I want the most optimized release code, do I need to comment out or delete those lines entirely?

I am using Visual Studio 2019 community and compiling for x64 but I want to know the answer more generally because I plan on compiling on multiple platforms. Thank you in advance.

Comment: A good compiler should.  Why not compile the code with your compiler and inspect the assembly to see if the brach exists or not?

Comment: Why not use `if constexpr` and remove all doubt?

Comment: One note about that, `if constexpr` only discards code of non-taken branches if the condition is dependent on a template.

Comment: Good old `#ifdef DEBUG`...

Comment: several things must go wrong to make this have an impact on performance, even if it is still in the code there is branch prediction and this one will be easy to predict. However, I wouldnt trust anybody but the compiler when it is about compiler optimizations. Did you try https://godbolt.org/ already?

Comment: @NathanOliver that's about checking if code compiles, afaik. It's not related discarding the code from output binary, which seems to be the question here.

Comment: This question is really about quality of implementation. It is not guaranteed that conditionals that the compiler can detect as false are "optimised away"  (e.g. in the sense of no emitted code in an object file or executable).  Most modern compilers, at higher optimisation settings, are likely to optimise away such things though.  The same goes for `if constexpr` - the C++ standard only requires that code diagnosis and execution proceed *as if* a false branch is discarded.  Whether that translates into the false branch being "optimised away" is, again, a quality of implementation concern.

Comment: Thanks folks. I appreciate the input and will check out a few of your ideas. I realize this "optimization" I am looking at is very small. And yeah Ayxan  I knew about #ifdef but I am a real stickler for readable code and imho I feel it is slightly less readable than standard language syntax. I'm sure I'm in the minority. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by discard, you mean remove from the final output binary, yes, most compilers will do that optimization ([Dead code elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_code_elimination)) for `if` and better yet, `if constexpr`. Do verify that with your compiler-generated asm if you want to be sure. However, if you're planning on having code that will not compile in release mode, then no. Regular `if` won't do and `if constexpr` will do only sometimes in templates. For that to work out, you can use pre-processor directives like `#ifdef DEBUG`.

Comment: The optimization name here is [Dead Code Elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_code_elimination) which might be of use to the OP (I find having a name for something makes understanding it/learning about it easier)

Comment: Thanks Ayxan and Adam. I had not heard that term (Dead Code Elimination). It indeed helps putting a name to it and brings up a plethora of online searches and info I hadn't had before. A great help from you all, thanks.